# Selenium C#. How can I download a file after it is opened on a new window?

Tags: c#, selenium, pdf, download, window

So I'm newbie using selenium, I'm trying to make an automatic process going to certain website, login with credentials and download a file, the problem comes when I click on that button for the download, it opens a new window of the browser and I don't know how to make Selenium know it has to go to that new window. It's a pdf file and I want it to download on a specific route.

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("//THIS IS THE WEBSITE URL//");
        driver.Manage().Window.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(990, 1040);
        driver.SwitchTo().Frame(0);
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("//CREDENTIAL")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("//CREDENTIAL")).SendKeys(myCredential);
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys(myPassword);
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("userCaptcha")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("userCaptcha")).SendKeys("captcha");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("submit")).Click();
        vars["WindowHandles"] = driver.WindowHandles;                //till this point login is succesfull
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#formReimpAcuse\\3Aj_idt50 > .ui-button-text")).Click();   //Here is where we find the button to start download pdf in a new browser window
        //No idea of what else to do.
```

Answer (score 0):

To download files easily you can disable the pdf viewer and tell the browser to download it automatically.

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("download.default_directory", "YOUR_DOWNLOAD_DIRECTORY");
chromeOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("download.prompt_for_download", False);
chromeOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("download.directory_upgrade", True);
chromeOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", True);


ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```